# Two systems of nonlinear ODE's and stability of a neutron star

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve two systems of nonlinear ODE's in order to determine the stability of a neutron star in modified gravity. First I set the equation of state, called Sly, which is the following monster:

```
acoeff = {6.22, 6.121, 0.005925, 0.16326, 6.48, 11.4971, 19.105, 
  0.8938, 6.54, 11.4950, -22.775, 1.5707, 4.3, 14.08, 27.80, -1.653, 
  1.50, 14.67}

pfact = 10*(299792458)^8/(6.67408/10^(11))^3/(1.989*10^(30))^2

rhofact = (1/10^3)*(299792458)^6/(6.67408/10^(11))^3/(1.989*10^(30))^2

p[r_] = (1/
     pfact)*10^((acoeff[[1]] + acoeff[[2]]*Log10[rhofact*rho[r]] + 
         acoeff[[3]]*(Log10[rhofact*rho[r]])^3)*(1/(Exp[
             acoeff[[5]]*(Log10[rhofact*rho[r]] - acoeff[[6]])] + 
            1))/(1 + acoeff[[4]]*Log10[rhofact*rho[r]]) + (acoeff[[
          7]] + acoeff[[8]]*
          Log10[rhofact*rho[r]])*(1/(Exp[
            acoeff[[9]]*(-Log10[rhofact*rho[r]] + acoeff[[10]])] + 
           1)) + (acoeff[[11]] + 
         acoeff[[12]]*
          Log10[rhofact*rho[r]])*(1/(Exp[
            acoeff[[13]]*(-Log10[rhofact*rho[r]] + acoeff[[14]])] + 
           1)) + (acoeff[[15]] + 
         acoeff[[16]]*
          Log10[rhofact*rho[r]])*(1/(Exp[
            acoeff[[17]]*(-Log10[rhofact*rho[r]] + acoeff[[18]])] + 
           1)));

p0[rho0_] := (1/
     pfact)*10^((acoeff[[1]] + acoeff[[2]]*Log10[rhofact*rho0] + 
         acoeff[[3]]*(Log10[rhofact*rho0])^3)*(1/(Exp[
             acoeff[[5]]*(Log10[rhofact*rho0] - acoeff[[6]])] + 
            1))/(1 + acoeff[[4]]*Log10[rhofact*rho0]) + (acoeff[[7]] +
          acoeff[[8]]*
          Log10[rhofact*rho0])*(1/(Exp[
            acoeff[[9]]*(-Log10[rhofact*rho0] + acoeff[[10]])] + 
           1)) + (acoeff[[11]] + 
         acoeff[[12]]*
          Log10[rhofact*rho0])*(1/(Exp[
            acoeff[[13]]*(-Log10[rhofact*rho0] + acoeff[[14]])] + 
           1)) + (acoeff[[15]] + 
         acoeff[[16]]*
          Log10[rhofact*rho0])*(1/(Exp[
            acoeff[[17]]*(-Log10[rhofact*rho0] + acoeff[[18]])] + 
           1)));

dpdrho[r_] = D[p[r], rho[r]];
```

Then, I set up the system for the star's interior:

```
R2eqs[a_, rho0_, R0_] := 
 NDSolve[{2*dpdrho[r]*rho'[r]*A[r] == -(rho[r] + p[r])*A'[r], 
   2*A'[r]*r*(1 + 2*a*R[r] + a*r*R'[r]) == 
    A[r]*(B[r]*r^2*(16 Pi*p[r] - a*R[r]^2) + 
       2 (1 + 2 a*R[r]) (B[r] - 1) - 8*a*r*R'[r]), 
   2*r*B'[r]*(1 + 2*a*R[r] + 
       a*r*R'[r]) == (2*(1 + 2*a*R[r]) (1 - B[r])*B[r] + 
      B[r]^2*r^2*(2*R[r] + 3*a*R[r]^2 + 16 Pi*(2*rho[r] + 3*p[r]))/
        3 + 2*a*r*R'[r]*
       B[r]*(B[r]*r^2*(R[r] + 3*a*R[r]^2 + 16 Pi*rho[r])/3 + 
          2 (1 - B[r])*(1 + 2*a*R[r]) + 4*a*r*R'[r])/(1 + 2*a*R[r])), 
   6*a*R''[r] == 
    B[r]*(R[r] + 8 Pi (3*p[r] - rho[r])) + 
     6*a*(B'[r]/2/B[r] - 2/r - A'[r]/2/A[r])*R'[r], 
   rho[0.001] == rho0, A[0.001] == 1, B[0.001] == 1, R[0.001] == R0, 
   R'[0.001] == 0.001*(R0 + 8 Pi*(3 p0[rho0] - rho0))/6/a}, {rho, A, 
   B, R, R'}, {r, 0.001, 17}, 
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]
```

There are 5 variables: the density of the star, the coefficient $A$ and $B$ of the spherically symmetric metric, the Ricci scalar $R$ and its derivative. Moreover, there are 2 free parameters, the central density $\rho_0$ and the central Ricci scalar $R_0$ (there is actually a third one, $a$, but let's fix it to unity for now). I have to choose them in order to have a good solution at infinity.

As you see, I had to use `Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}` in order to solve for the derivatives. **Now the first question**. When I was using a simpler equation of state, e.g. $p = \kappa_0 \rho^2$, I didn't need to use Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"} and I could use instead `Method -> {"EventLocator", "Event" -> rho[r]}` which allowed me to stop the integrator when $\rho$ became vanishing, which corresponds to the star's radius. **Is there a way to use both methods combined?**

Following the suggestion of @User21 I modified the code using `ParametricNDSolve` and `WhenEvent` as follows:

```
R2eqs = 
 ParametricNDSolve[{2*dpdrho[r]*rho'[r]*A[r] == -(rho[r] + p[r])*
     A'[r], 2*A'[r]*r*(1 + 2*a*R[r] + a*r*R'[r]) == 
    A[r]*(B[r]*r^2*(16 Pi*p[r] - a*R[r]^2) + 
       2 (1 + 2 a*R[r]) (B[r] - 1) - 8*a*r*R'[r]), 
   2*r*B'[r]*(1 + 2*a*R[r] + 
       a*r*R'[r]) == (2*(1 + 2*a*R[r]) (1 - B[r])*B[r] + 
      B[r]^2*r^2*(2*R[r] + 3*a*R[r]^2 + 16 Pi*(2*rho[r] + 3*p[r]))/
        3 + 2*a*r*R'[r]*
       B[r]*(B[r]*r^2*(R[r] + 3*a*R[r]^2 + 16 Pi*rho[r])/3 + 
          2 (1 - B[r])*(1 + 2*a*R[r]) + 4*a*r*R'[r])/(1 + 2*a*R[r])), 
   6*a*R''[r] == 
    B[r]*(R[r] + 8 Pi (3*p[r] - rho[r])) + 
     6*a*(B'[r]/2/B[r] - 2/r - A'[r]/2/A[r])*R'[r], 
   rho[0.001] == rho0, A[0.001] == 1, B[0.001] == 1, R[0.001] == R0, 
   R'[0.001] == 0.001*(R0 + 8 Pi*(3 p0[rho0] - rho0))/6/a, 
   WhenEvent[rho[r] == 0, "StopIntegration"]}, {rho, A, B, R, R'}, {r,
    0.001, 17}, {a, rho0, R0}, 
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]
```

Now, when I call the density I get:

```
rho[1, 0.00162, 0.017] /. R2eqs

ParametricNDSolve::mconly: For the method IDA, only machine real code is available. Unable to continue with complex values or beyond floating-point exceptions.
```

A part from the error, the code works and I can plot the density of the star. And I can determine the star's radius as follows:

```
In[30]:= StarRadius[a_, rho0_, R0_] := 
 InterpolatingFunctionDomain[First[rho[a, rho0, R0] /. R2eqs]][[1, 1, 
   2]]

In[31]:= StarRadius[1, 0.00162, 0.017]

Out[31]= 7.80987
```

Probably I have thus answered to my first question, though should you have any suggestion of improvement they would be very welcome.

Second part. I set up a second system, which evolves the equations with no matter (thus no $\rho$ and no equation of state) from the star's radius to infinity (that is, $r = 100$). Now, I want to use again `ParametricNDSolve`:

```
    R2eqsOUT = 
 ParametricNDSolve[{A'[r]*2*r*(1 + 2*a*R[r] + a*r*R'[r]) == 
    A[r]*(B[r]*r^2*(-a*R[r]^2) + 2 (1 + 2 a*R[r]) (B[r] - 1) - 
       8*a*r*R'[r]), 
   2*r*B'[r]*(1 + 2*a*R[r] + a*r*R'[r]) == 
    2*(1 + 2*a*R[r]) (1 - B[r])*
      B[r] + (B[r]^2*r^2*(2*R[r] + 3*a*R[r]^2)/3) + (2*a*r*R'[r]*
       B[r]*(B[r]*r^2*(R[r] + 3*a*R[r]^2)/3 + 
          2 (1 - B[r])*(1 + 2*a*R[r]) + 4*a*r*R'[r])/(1 + 2*a*R[r])), 
   6*a*R''[r] == 
    B[r]*R[r] + 6*a*((B'[r]/2/B[r]) - 2/r - (A'[r]/2/A[r]))*R'[r], 
   A[StarRadius[a, rho0, R0]] == 
    Evaluate[A[a, rho0, R0][StarRadius[a, rho0, R0]] /. R2eqs], 
   B[StarRadius[a, rho0, R0]] == 
    Evaluate[B[a, rho0, R0][StarRadius[a, rho0, R0]] /. R2eqs], 
   R[StarRadius[a, rho0, R0]] == 
    Evaluate[R[a, rho0, R0][StarRadius[a, rho0, R0]] /. R2eqs], 
   R'[StarRadius[a, rho0, R0]] == 
    Evaluate[R'[a, rho0, R0][StarRadius[a, rho0, R0]] /. R2eqs]}, {A, 
   B, R, R'}, {r, StarRadius[a, rho0, R0], 100}, {a, rho0, R0}]

Part::partd: Part specification InterpolatingFunctionDomain[a][[1,1,2]] is longer than depth of object.

Part::partd: Part specification InterpolatingFunctionDomain[a][[1,1,2]] is longer than depth of object.

Part::partd: Part specification InterpolatingFunctionDomain[a][[1,1,2]] is longer than depth of object.

General::stop: Further output of Part::partd will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

And when I try to plot $\rho$, I get:

```
In[33]:= rho[1, 0.00162, 0.015] /. R2eqsOUT

Out[33]= rho[1, 0.00162, 0.015]
```

I guess the problem is in `StarRadius[a, rho0, R0]` which calls the parameters too soon (or late), but I really don't know.

If these issues were solved, I would then focus on the solution for $R$. I know from the boundary conditions of my problem that $R \to 0$ when $r \to \infty$ and some analytical approximation shows that $R$ does so exponentially. Numerically, I could reproduce such exponentially decaying behaviour for $R$ only if I choose the correct initial $R_0$ and $\rho_0$. If I do not do so, $R$ grows exponentially with a lot of warnings by Mathematica.

So, what I am trying to do is to set up a shooting method. I fix $r = 20$ and try to find combinations of $R_0$ and $\rho_0$ which give back a $R(20)$ almost vanishing. For example I could use

```
FindRoot[R[1,0.00162,R0][20]/.R2eqsOUT,{R0,0.001}]
```

which would give me the value of $R_0$ which makes $R$ vanishing at $r = 20$. Actually, it does not vanish strictly speaking, so maybe it would be nice to have a routine which could tell me for which $R_0$ $R(20)$ is less than say $10^{-6}$.

Comment: You could have a look at `WhenEvent` and at `ParametricNDSolve`.

Comment: I tried and use `ParametricNDSolve` and it does its job fine in the first system, inside the star. However, it seems not working (more possibly I am doing something wrong) in the second system, outside the star, because I need as IC's here the solutions of the first system at the star's radius (which is also determined via the first system). Perhaps using IC's such as `A[StarRadius[a, rho0, R0]] == 
 AR2[StarRadius[a, rho0, R0], a, rho0, R0]` where `StarRadius[a_, rho0_, R0_] := 
 FindRoot[rho[a, rho0, R0][r] /. R2eqs, {r, 0.001}][[1, 2]]` creates some issue.

Comment: The question is a series of functions.  Please provide the actual code to produce a result.

Comment: I modified my original question using `ParametricNDSolve` and `WhenEvent` as suggested by @user21. Maybe I didn't get your point but I copied in the question my actual code, though I am not sure how to properly paste the Mathematica output.